# Get real image coordinates from mouse location in PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Windows form I have a PictureBox which image is loaded from a directory.

I need to display the real dimension of the image into the PictureBox, for example the image (width=1024,height=768), and the picturebox (width=800, height=600).

I want to load the image into the PictureBox with same pixel values. So that when I point anywhere in PictureBox I get the pixel value same with the pixel value that I get if I point to the real image (example get dimension using Photoshop).

Tried so far but no success:

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image);
    MessageBox.Show("X=" + (1024/ 800) * me.X + ", Y=" + (768/ 600) *me.Y);
}
```

Comment: You want picture box to set as image pixels? Or you want to show pixels on pointing anywhere in picture box?

Comment: I want to show pixels on pointing anywhere in picturebox where values same as when I am pointing anywhere in the real image that is loaded

Comment: Btw: There is no need to do this `MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;` `e` has already the same type as `me`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1024 / 800` and `768 / 600` are both integer division which produce `1`

change order of operations:

```
MessageBox.Show("X=" + (1024 * me.X / 800)  + ", Y=" + (768 * me.Y / 600));
```

---

Here is complete method (assuming `PictureBox1.SizeMode` is set to `StretchImage`). Use real width and height values, not "magic" constants 1024x768 or 800x600

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs me)
{            
    Image b = PictureBox1.Image;
    int x = b.Width * me.X / PictureBox1.Width;
    int y = b.Height * me.Y / PictureBox1.Height;
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("X={0}, Y={1}", x, y));
}
```

Comment: @user3405070, is there any improvement? I assume `PictureBox1.SizeMode` is set to StretchImage. does image really have size 1024x768? use real size in formula like this:  `Bitmap b = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image); MessageBox.Show("X=" + (b.Width * me.X / PictureBox1.Width)  + ", Y=" + (b.Height * me.Y / PictureBox1.Height) );`

Comment: Is it necessary to create a new Bitmap? Could you not just use the size of the Image property (`PictureBox1.Image.Height`)?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, I agree with you. I was about to fix it (`Bitmap b = (Bitmap)PictureBox1.Image;`) but forgot in process. Your suggestion is better, actually, thanks

Comment: @ASh Thank you very much, it works very well, `Bitmap b = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image); MessageBox.Show("X=" + (b.Width * me.X / PictureBox1.Width) + ", Y=" + (b.Height * me.Y / PictureBox1.Height) );`