# C#- Place Picturebox on another Picturebox with real image coordinates issues

Tags: c#

I managed to get real image coordinates from mouse location in Picturebox. [thanks to those who helped.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574437/get-real-image-coordinates-from-mouse-location-in-picturebox) What I need to do next is to place the child picturebox inside the parent picturebox which loaded an image uses its real dimension.

I used these lines of code to placed child(Picturebox2) into parent(Picturebox1):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var pos = this.PointToScreen(Picturebox2.Location);
        pos= Picturebox1.PointToClient(pos);
        Picturebox2.Parent = Picturebox1;
     }
```

With these code to move the child location inside parent on mouse pointing:

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs me)
{            
   Image b = PictureBox1.Image;
   int x = b.Width * me.X / PictureBox1.Width;
   int y = b.Height * me.Y / PictureBox1.Height;

   pictureBox2.Location = new Point(x,y);
}
```

The problem is that it placed the child Picturebox with wrong coordinates, I supposed it gets the parent Picturebox coordinates somehow instead of the real image coordinates.

Comment: Would you just not assign `pictureBox2.Location = pictureBox1.Location` in your MouseDown function?

Comment: You are coding the the wrong event: If you want to move the nested control with the mouse you need to use __its__ MouseDown&Move events! Also: Using the 'real' coordinates makes no sense, as both mouse and location are in actual pixels, which should be considered 'real'. Scaled pixels are not used until you, say, start to draw..

Comment: Ok, what I want to do is not really to move the object by mouse pointing, above code is just a sample that I need to implement into my project. I want the function to placed the child picturebox into the parent picturebox where the child coordinates is the same when i want to place the object on the real image. To make it simpler, it is likely placing child object into the parent object that serves as a template. please tell me if I am in the right track.

Comment: I did it successfully when I placed image into the template image in a specific coordinates and save the image, but now I want it to display in picturebox at runtime.